# Nexus 3 repo: Old paths not working after upgrade

Tags: maven, nuget, nexus

I've recently upgraded nexus repo from *2.10 -> 3.17*.

It has been upgraded successfully, but the old artifact's download/upload paths for are not working.

I've checked for `maven` and `nuget`, and found the problem in both of them.

I've already set legacy path configuration as mentioned [here](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/upgrading/upgrade-procedures#UpgradeProcedures-ConfiguringLegacyURLPaths). Restarted my nexus server but still facing the issue.

I've checked start logs & it is showing updated configuration:

```
2019-07-14 05:05:04,968-0400 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.
internal.HttpBridgeModule.legacy='true'
```

**For nuget:**

Old path that was working:

```
http://mynexus.intranet.myco.com/repositories/Nuget-NetPort/MY_APP/2.0.2/MY_APP-2.0.2.nupkg
```

New path:

```
http://mynexus.intranet.myco.com/repository/Nuget-NetPort/MY_APP/2.0.2
```

**For maven:**

Old path that was working:

```
http://mynexus.intranet.myco.com/service/local/repositories/devuser/content/com/mygroup/appdomain/myjavaapp/61ee8qy/myjavaappupdated-61ee8qy.zip
```

New path:

```
http://mynexus.intranet.myco.com/service/local/repositories/devuser/com/mygroup/appdomain/myjavaapp/61ee8qy/myjavaappupdated-61ee8qy.zip
```

Comment: The old NXRM2 nuget path doesn't work for me.  What version are you using?  For maven, I suspect the service/local may be a REST call which is not backwards compatible to NXRM3.